# Java - Optimize substring from the following code snippets for better performance

Tags: java, substring

The following code in Java uses recursion to do a rotation from a string. I am wondering if is there a better way of coding this.

```
public static String rotateString(String s, int leftRotation, int rightRotation){
    while(s.length() > 0){
        for(int x = 0; x < leftRotation; x++){
            if(s.charAt(0) == 'X') s = s.substring(3) + s.substring(0, 3);
            else s = s.substring(1) + s.substring(0, 1);
        }
        int dK = s.length() - 1;
        int dKx = s.length() - 3;
        for(int y = 0; y < rightRotation; y++){
            if(s.charAt(dK) == 'Z') s = s.substring(dKx) + s.substring(0, dKx);
            else s = s.substring(dK) + s.substring(0, dK);
        }
        return s;
    }
    return s;
}
    
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println(rotateString(bufferedReader.readLine(), 3, 6));
}
```

From the code above is changing sequence of character from a specific string by rotating the word where the first word become the last or the last word become the first, for example the input is:

> abcdXYZefgXYZhij

If the words begins or ends with "XYZ", then all "XYZ" words get leftRotated and otherwise. For example:

1. "abcdXYZefgXYZhij" leftRotation 1 time = "bcdXYZefgXYZhija".
2. "abcdXYZefgXYZhij" leftRotation 5 times = "efgXYZhijabcdXYZ".
3. "abcdXYZefgXYZhij" rightRotation 1 time = "jabcdXYZefgXYZhi".
4. "abcdXYZefgXYZhij" rightRotation 4 time = "XYZhijabcdXYZefg".

Comment: "The following code in Java uses recursion" - I don't see any recursive calls. I'm also not quite sure I understand your rotation requirements, a few more examples might help (e.g. how exactly does rotating left 5 times get you from `abcdXYZefgXYZhij` to `efgXYZhijabcdXYZ`?). 
That being said, please define "a better way of coding this" - Easier to read? Better performance (did you measure)? 
If it's actually _words_ you want to rotate I'd start with splitting the string into words (i.e. a string array) then rotate the array and finally reconstruct the string.

Comment: @Thomas sorry, I just realized, gonna edit it.

Comment: Can you post complete code? "dorongKiri" and "dorongKanan" are used, but not declared anywhere.

Comment: @Kaan I just corrected the code above

Comment: Can add an explanation why left rotation of `"abcdXYZefgXYZhij"` applied `5` times is `"efgXYZhijabcdXYZ"` ? I would expect it to be `"YZefgXYZhijabcdX"`.

Comment: And what is the final result in plain words - the given string rotated `i` times to the left, and then `j` times to the right, am I correct?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko "XYZefgXYZhijabcd" is the result after the 4th left rotation, at this point the words begin with "XYZ", so if the system do left rotation again, all "XYZ" words get left rotated and otherwise happens. And yes, as the code above, the final result is "hijabcdXYZefgXYZ".